# Maybe Haskell implementation

Tags: haskell

```
step :: [Int] -> String -> [Int]
step (x:y:ys) "*" = (x*y):ys
step (x:y:ys) "+" = (x + y):ys
step (x:y:ys) "-" = (y - x):ys
step xs numString = read numString : xs
```

I am expanding my knowledge from, 
http://learnyouahaskell.com/functionally-solving-problems, I wanna try to do some eroor handling using `Maybe`. Can anyone give me some hint or any useful keyword on defining below function(if my idea is right)? I wanna return `Just sts` when I successfully input value and `Nothing`when I didn't. Dunno if my concept is right, anyone correct me.

```
 step2:: [Int] -> String -> Maybe [Int]
```

Comment: You're not allowed to remove the code from your question just because you got your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your type signature is right. Here's one possible implementation:

```
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

step2 :: [Int] -> String -> Maybe [Int]
step2 (x:y:ys) "*" = Just $ (x*y):ys
step2 (x:y:ys) "+" = Just $ (x + y):ys
step2 (x:y:ys) "-" = Just $ (y - x):ys
step2 xs numString | Just num <- readMaybe numString = Just $ num:xs
step2 _ _ = Nothing
```

The basic idea is for all of your existing cases, wrap them in `Just`, and then at the end, have a catch-all of `Nothing`. There's a bit of special handling for `read`, since it just throws an error if it fails, so you need to use `readMaybe` and pattern-match on it instead.

---

There's another way you can write it that shortens a bit:

```
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

step2 :: [Int] -> String -> Maybe [Int]
step2 (x:y:ys) "*" = Just $ (x*y):ys
step2 (x:y:ys) "+" = Just $ (x + y):ys
step2 (x:y:ys) "-" = Just $ (y - x):ys
step2 xs numString = fmap (:xs) (readMaybe numString)
```

We were able to make this change for a few reasons:

- `readMaybe` returns its result wrapped in the same type that our function will (`Maybe`)
- That common type (`Maybe`) is a `Functor`

Because of that, we can apply `fmap` to the output of `readMaybe` to combine the last two cases. For the `Maybe` type, `fmap` works by leaving a `Nothing` as a `Nothing`, or changing a `Just x` to `Just (f x)`, which is exactly what we were doing anyway.

Comment: @THEK The last case should already handle every possible case. Can you give a concrete example of one that you think is missing?

Comment: @THEK: If you want to include more information about a particular failure, you can use `Either String` instead of `Maybe`, e.g., `step2 (x : y : ys) "+" = Right ((x + y) : ys); step2 _ "+" = Left "stack underflow evaluating + operator"`. For more structure and type safety, you could define `data StepError = UnderflowError String [Int] | LiteralError String | …` then use `Either StepError` instead of `EitherString`, e.g., `step2 xs op@"+" = Left (UnderflowError op xs); step2 xs numString = case readMaybe numString of { Just num -> Right (num : xs); Nothing -> Left (LiteralError numString) } `

Comment: @JonPurdy The switch from `Maybe` to `Either` alone makes that worth a separate answer, where it will be far more readable anyway :).

Comment: The fallback case is redundant.

Comment: @dfeuer In fairness, it wasn't redundant in the version of the answer that I wrote. Anyway, it's fixed now. (And I also added some more explanation.)